# The 'email' key is missing from the given credentials array

Tags: laravel, adldap

after updating my Laravel and Adldap2 to version 6.0,i'm receiving this error when i'm trying to authenticate,

**

> The 'email' key is missing from the given credentials array

**

what is the reason behind that ?

i haven't changed anything in my LoginController or Auth.php or anywhere else,

my config/auth.php

```
<?php

return [


    'defaults' => [
        'guard' => 'web',
        'passwords' => 'users',
    ],


    'guards' => [
        'web' => [
            'driver' => 'session',
            'provider' => 'users',
        ],

        'api' => [
            'driver' => 'token',
            'provider' => 'users',
        ],
    ],



    'providers' => [
        'users' => [
            'driver' => 'ldap', //'eloquent',
            'model' => App\User::class,     
            'table' => 'users',
        ],

    ],


    'passwords' => [
        'users' => [
            'provider' => 'users',
            'table' => 'password_resets',
            'expire' => 60,
        ],
    ],

];
```

Comment: Kindly check this out https://github.com/Adldap2/Adldap2-Laravel/issues/714

Comment: thanks, i checked but i coudn't find the solution, laravel Authenticates through username and password, where should i add the 'Email' key ???

Answer (score 0):

After upgrading to Laravel 6 and adldap 6 You need to republish config files.

https://github.com/Adldap2/Adldap2-Laravel/blob/master/docs/upgrading.md